# Can I extend Androids Contacts list database to have additional icon?

Tags: android, contacts, extend

The [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html) states that there is an option to extend the contacts database.
What I would like to do is to add an additional icon to the standard contacts list that when it is pressed will cause my application to be notified and handle the call.
Seemd like Whatsup has this kind of icon in the contacts list but it is not clear how exactly this is done.

Thanks,
  Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public final class ContactsContract
```

It Simply says Android Contact Provider is a final class. From Java 101 we know we can not extend final class. So the answer is no.

```
I would like to do is to add an additional icon to the standard contacts list
```

I am not seeing this as a big problem. You can create your own `ContentProvider` and retrieve data when you display back this data to your app. You can use an ID field to map original Contact with your own contact. You can add as many field as you want.

```
when it is pressed will cause my application to be notified and handle the call.
```

You can not modify standard phonebook app but you can have your own phonebook and do whatever you wanna do like add button with each contact or additional image to display. Considering those additional data are stored on your ContentProvider.

But, for Handling call from standard phonebook app you do not need any custom content provider. 
You just need following `IntentFilter` in your `AndroidManifest` file.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />                
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
         </intent-filter>
```

And the permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

This will provide user an option to pick a dialer application which going to be your app or the standard dialer app to complete the dialing process.

Comment: If I understand correctly, users will not see my app icon in the standard contacts list, but when clicking to make a call, they will be able to choose my app to handle it. If yes, what intent filter do I need to define if I want to override sending an email rather than making a call?